# How to increase days via button/variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a due date with an Extend button where if clicked on, it will add 7 days to the latest due date. However, the page just refreshes itself without adding the days.

The first due date is done by modifying a date in the table database so that the due date will always start off to be 7 days ahead of the `IssuesDate`. Initially, I tried to put another `$datetime->modify('+7 days');` code after the `Extend` button but that will just add the days and will just reset when the page resets. Adding before the `echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');` will just ended up with every due date 14 days ahead.

```
<?php if($result->ReturnDate==""){?>
<td class="center">
   <span style="color:red">
   <?php   
      $datetime = new DateTime($result->IssuesDate); 
      $datetime->modify('+7 days');
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $datetime->modify('+7 days');   
        }                                                           
      echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');?>
   </span>
</td>
<td class="center">
   <form action="test-loan2.php" method="post" name="extend">
      <a href="test-loan2.php?rid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->rid);?>">
      <button type="submit "class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit" name="submit"></i>Extend</button>
   </form>
</td>
```

Currently, I'm trying to use the form method instead hoping to extend 7 more days to the initial 7 days due date with the  `Extend` button as the "submit button". However, this just refreshes the page without adding the days

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't think you can submit the ```i``` tag, which you've given the ```name``` "submit", so your ```isset``` check will never succeed. You could perhaps change this to be a hidden input field with the increment value, or simply check if the request method is POST and increment based on that. (```$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']```)

Comment: `name="submit"` simply belongs on the `button` element itself, not the `i` nested inside of it.

Comment: Well the button tag cannot contain more tags. Please see documentation for button: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp. Also the hyperlink above the button needs to be closed. Otherwise it will cover the button and the form wont submit. It will just reload the page or redirect to another page

Comment: @NadirLatif _“Well the button tag cannot contain more tags.”_ – _absolutely_ not true. The content model for `button` in HTML5 is [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (with the added limitation, that is must not be any of the _interactive_ elements, which `i` is not.)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add name="submit" to the button

```
<button name="submit" type="submit "class="btn btn-primary">
```

I debugged that by adding a "echo 'here';" in the if(isset[$_POST['submit']) block,  which instantly told me that the submit button wasnt working, you should get the habit of doing that